# Adding PostgreSQL installer to my own application installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, postgresql, installation

I created a Visual Studio 2010 installer project and added the `postgresql-9.2.401-windows.exe` file to it. In the "Commit" custom action, I added that file, removed any arguments and set `InstallerClass` to `False`.

Now, when I run my application's installer, the PostgreSQL setup starts up, shows its splash screen and then jumps to 100% CPU usage and starts leaking memory for a long time (certainly longer than a few minutes), after which it bails out. Running the `.exe` on that computer works just fine.

How should I package PostgreSQL in my installer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I don't like programs that silently install the standard PostgreSQL for Windows. It's deeply annoying to get mailing list posts from people who're asking "What's this PostgreSQL thing and why is it using 88 bajillion megabytes of RAM, I didn't ask for it, remove it now!".

(Yes, I'm mostly talking about a certain annoying gambling card-counting program with the initials PT whose name I will not mention directly).

If you're going to bundle PostgreSQL it'd be great if you could use a non-default port and non-default data directory. If you install a service to auto-start it, don't use the default service name `postgresql-[version]` but something like `myapp-database` or `myapp-postgres`.

This is all done much more easily if you just bundle the PostgreSQL binaries in your installer then create the service yourself with your installer tools or via `sc.exe`. You may choose to simply `pg_ctl` start/stop the server from within your program, though this requires some thought about access permissions to the data directory.

The downside is that when there are PostgreSQL updates you need to update your installer. On the other hand, you probably don't *want* people upgrading PostgreSQL independently of your software updates.

I suggest using the .zip binaries from [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) and bundling them into your installer directly.

If you really must use the executable installer [the documentation contains instructions on silent installation](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide).

Comment: I wasn't going to do it silently, and be very specific about it in my installer and documentation. It is a vital part of the entire system. I have been looking into the .zip bundling and will implement that probably in a later stage (I have a deadline now...). I have been looking into Inno Setup, which is quite a lot easier than the VS setup project.

Comment: @BartFriederichs You'll find changing from one to the other pretty painful, but eh, up to you. See http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide

Comment: It doesn't have to keep working between versions. The one I am building/packaging now is for internal beta testing. The release will get the ZIP bundled version.