# Tuning/restart postgresql server from code on application startup

Tags: c#, postgresql, configuration

I have an application in C# that should set `shared_buffers` of postgresql server to at least 512MB on the app's first start. So, I need to perform the following operations in my code:

1. Check if `shared_buffers` are less than 512MB.
2. Set `shared_buffers` to 512MB.
3. Restart postgresql server in order to apply changes.
4. Continue running application after restart is completed.

How to do this in code?

Comment: Does `shared_buffers` values change after your app's first start ? if so how ?

Comment: No, I need to change it only once on the first start. Users probably have default postgresql settings when they start  application at the first time.

Comment: So why you need _Check if shared_buffers are less than 512MB._ ?

Comment: Because possibly user set it manually to higher value and I don't need to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.4 and above you can use [`ALTER SYSTEM SET`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) to modify `postgresql.auto.conf` to add parameters.

So you could:

```
SHOW shared_buffers;
```

and if it's too low:

```
ALTER SYSTEM
  SET shared_buffers = '512MB';
```

You must then restart PostgreSQL. This, by design, cannot be done from within PostgreSQL because if there's a problem during restart then you can't connect to it anymore, so you could lock yourself out too easily. You can *reload the config* with `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`, but `shared_buffers` only takes effect at full restart, not just a config reload.

So your app will need to use an external OS-specific and install-method-specific way to restart PostgreSQL once you've made the config change. Or just tell the user to restart it for you.

To restart:

- For any platform (Windows, Mac or Linux) with PostgreSQL custom installed and managed, use `pg_ctl restart`.
- On Windows, installed as a service: use `net stop [servicename]` then `net start [servicename]`
- On older Linux (pre-systemd) with PostgreSQL installed system-wide: Use the `service` command, e.g. `service restart [servicename]`. This must be run as root or via sudo.
- On newer Linux (systemd) with PostgreSQL installed system-wide: Use `systemctl restart [servicename].service`

---

If you're using an older PostgreSQL without `ALTER SYSTEM SET` you'll have to open, modify and write `postgresql.conf`.

To avoid having to parse and modify the whole `postgresql.conf` I find it useful to append the `include_dir = 'conf.d'` option and then create a `conf.d/myapp.conf` in the datadir with just the config overrides I want.

[`include_dir` is available in 9.3 and newer](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html). For still-older versions you've just got to modify `postgresql.conf` directly.

---

If your app is responsible for installing and setting up PostgreSQL in the first place you can just set the desired `shared_buffers` in the config file  after `initdb` and before starting up the database.

If you are bundling PostgreSQL in your application this is the approach I strongly prefer. Don't use the installer, just bundle the binaries in your installer. Start PostgreSQL when your app starts by invoking the `postgres` command directly, or by using `pg_ctl`. Stop it when your program exits. Use a non-default port (i.e. don't use port 5432), do *not* install under a `postgres` user, put the data directory into something like `%PROGRAMDATA%\MyApp\postgres` and otherwise avoid conflicting with official PostgreSQL installs. This will save you a lot of grief.

See:

- [Installation of postgresql with NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24625490/398670)
- [Adding PostgreSQL installer to my own application installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18058503/398670)
- [How to install postgres with NSIS with all parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30924913/398670)

Comment: 1. How to get a full path to `postgresql.conf`? 
2. Is it safe and effective enough to stop postgresql server after application exit? I see standart postgresql server installed as a service in Windows is doing some work with database after application has been shut down. Also, what if app closed unexpectedly or user just killed the process? Then, myapp_postgres server will continue to run.

Comment: @AndrewPlakhotnyi `SHOW config_file` gives you the config file location, either as a full path or relative to the data directory (`SHOW data_directory`). Of course that's with the server running. The server looks for the config file in the datadirectory by default, unless you start it with command line options telling it to look elsewhere.

Comment: @AndrewPlakhotnyi As for being safe to app manage it - honestly, nearly impossible to say since I know nothing about your application. It's generally reasonable enough, and it's not like it matters much if PostgreSQL stays running after an app crash/force quit. Your app just has to notice that it's already running when it starts back up. Alternately, you can register it as a Windows service (but *use a different port, data directory and service name to the default PostgreSQL installs please*) using `pg_ctl register` then use the usual Windows APIs for service management.

Comment: @AndrewPlakhotnyi  Depends mainly on whether you want multiple user accounts on the same machine to share the same data in your app or not. Both approaches are fine IMO.

Comment: @CraigRinger, opinions on difference btwn `pg_ctl restart` and `net stop ...` on a Windows machine?

Comment: @raphael If it's configured as a Windows service, use `net`. If it's running standalone, use `pg_ctl`.